# Why doesnt my For-Loop Complete Collecting Data to hold in a Dynamically Allocated Array?

Tags: c++, function, for-loop, struct, dynamic-arrays

My for loop inside my function doesn't complete its full run. After asking for the student's address it just outputs:

```
"Enter City: Enter Age: Enter Name: Enter Street Address: Enter City: Enter 
Age: Enter Name: Enter Street Address: Enter City: Enter Age:"
```

Instead of letting the user input the rest of their info. Basically the for loop should loop for each student. So if there are 3 students it should loop three times so each student can input their information. 
This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct Address
{
   char sStreet[255];
   char sCity[255];
};

struct Student
{
   char sName[255];
   Address address;
   int nAge;
};

void initializeData(Student * pStudents, int size);
// void sortData(Student * pStudents, int size);
// void displayData(Student * pStudents, int size);

int main()
{
  int size = 0;

  cout << "Enter the number of students in your classroom: ";
  cin >> size;

  Student * pStudents = new Student[size];

  initializeData(pStudents, size);

  delete [] pStudents;
  pStudents = NULL;

  return 0;
}

void initializeData(Student * pStudents, int size)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    cout << "Enter Name: ";
    cin >> pStudents[i].sName;

    cout << "Enter Street Address: ";
    cin >> pStudents[i].address.sStreet;

    cout << "Enter City: ";
    cin >> pStudents[i].address.sCity;

    cout << "Enter Age: ";
    cin >> pStudents[i].nAge;
  }
}
```

I'm really confused as to why it is not finishing its loop :( There is more to this assignment but I'm stuck here. I am not sure why the for loop isn't fully completing and I tried to get help during class time but no one could help me with this problem.

**UPDATE: Thank you to both users who commented first! Both of your suggestions helped me and after fixing my code this is what is working now:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct Address
{
  char sStreet[255];
  char sCity[255];
};

struct Student
{
  char sName[255];
  Address address;
  int nAge;
};

void initializeData(Student * pStudents, int size);
// void sortData(Student * pStudents, int size);
// void displayData(Student * pStudents, int size);

int main()
{
  int size = 0;

  cout << "Enter the number of students in your classroom: ";
  cin >> size;

  cin.ignore();

  Student * pStudents = new Student[size];

  initializeData(pStudents, size);

  delete [] pStudents;
  pStudents = NULL;

  return 0;
}

void initializeData(Student * pStudents, int size)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    cout << "Enter Name: ";
    cin.getline(pStudents[i].sName, 255);

    cout << "Enter Street Address: ";
    cin.getline(pStudents[i].address.sStreet, 255);

    cout << "Enter City: ";
    cin.getline(pStudents[i].address.sCity, 255);

    cout << "Enter Age: ";
    cin >> pStudents[i].nAge;

    cin.ignore();
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly:** The problem is using `cin` to read the string that contains space. For example, to read  `pStudents[i].sName`, if you enter, "`John Kim`". Then `John` will be in the variable `pStudents[i].sName` and `Kim` will be stored in `pStudents[i].address.sCity`. The reason for it is `cin` stops reading and move to next variable read if it founds space.

**Secondly:** If your input is newline terminated then `getline` can be used, as for example `getline(cin, pStudents[i].sName);` Also, look at the definition of  `getline`:

```
istream& getline (istream& is, string& str, char delim);
```

You can specify the delimitation character as delim, the default for `getline` is newline.

**Thirdly:** `getline` accepts parameter as `string`, so your character arrays are replaced with string as for example:

```
   string sStreet;
   string sCity;

   string sName;
```

Updated code given below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct Address
{
   string sStreet;
   string sCity;
};

struct Student
{
   string sName;
   Address address;
   int nAge;
};

void initializeData(Student * pStudents, int size);
// void sortData(Student * pStudents, int size);
// void displayData(Student * pStudents, int size);

int main()
{
  int size = 0;

  cout << "Enter the number of students in your classroom: ";
  cin >> size;

  Student * pStudents = new Student[size];

  initializeData(pStudents, size);

  delete [] pStudents;
  pStudents = NULL;

  return 0;
}

void initializeData(Student * pStudents, int size)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    cout << "Enter Name: ";
    getline(cin, pStudents[i].sName);

    cout << "Enter Street Address: ";
    getline(cin, pStudents[i].address.sStreet);

    cout << "Enter City: ";
    getline(cin, pStudents[i].address.sCity);

    cout << "Enter Age: ";
    cin >> pStudents[i].nAge;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I was using getline at first but with getline it skips the Name input and goes straight to the Street Address. So this is my output using cin.getline: "Enter Name: Enter Street Address:     "

Comment: You can copy and paste my code to test. And if you have any other confusion, then you can ask in post.

Comment: It started working once I put cin.ignore() after each input, however lets say I have 3 students. After I enter the first student's information it does the same output: "Enter Age: Enter Name: Enter Street Address: Enter City: Enter Age: Enter Name: Enter Street Address: Enter City: Enter Age: "

Answer (score 0):

`operator>>` does not extract the line break when the user types in the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. You have to call `cin.ignore()` after calling `operator>>`, especially after reading integers, eg:

```
cout << "Enter the number of students in your classroom: ";
cin >> size;
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize_t>::max(), '\n');
```

You can use `cin.getline()` instead of `operator>>` to read a whole line of text into a `char[]`.  It will skip the line break for you, eg:

```
cout << "Enter Name: ";
cin.getline(pStudents[i].sName, 255);
```

Or better, use `std::getline` instead to read a line into a `std::string`, which also skips the line break for you, and then you can use `std::istringstream` to parse the string as needed, eg:

```
struct Student
{
    std::string sName;
    ...
};

cout << "Enter the number of students in your classroom: ";
std::string tmp;
getline(cin, tmp);
istringstream(tmp) >> size;

...

cout << "Enter Name: ";
getline(cin, pStudents[i].sName);
```

You should consider one of these approaches anyway, so you can read names, addresses, and cities that have multiple words in them, as `operator>>` stops reading when it sees any whitespace character (or in the case of integers, when it sees non-integral characters).